# What can cause `stack build` to keep unregistering local dependencies every time?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I've tried `stack clean`, and also removing `.stack-work`.
But still, every time I run build it unregisters 5 (the same) packages.
`stack build --dry-run` tells me the list, but not any reason why.

I've also recently upgraded from 1.4.1

Also, if it is not quite simple how to figure this out, I'd like to get back to using 1.4.1. Any simple way to downgrade `haskell-stack` to that version?

#### Edit 1

Downgrading to 1.4.0 didn't help. About 70 packages got unregistered and rebuilt, and after that I got into the same 5-unregister-loop.

So I thought, where else could have my local state be corrupted since ~yesterday? `~/.stack`! So  I've (re)moved my `~/.stack` folder, and also `.stack-work` folder, thinking that if anything could have gone wrong it's in these two places, and now I am in an even worse of a rut. Now the constant unregister cycle includes 23 packages (some of them quite heavy) instead of just 5.

```
Would unregister locally:
cairo-0.13.3.1 (missing dependencies: gtk2hs-buildtools)
dump-0.3.0 (missing dependencies: haskell-src-meta, interpolatedstring-perl6)
entropy-0.3.7
ghcjs-dom-0.2.4.0 (missing dependencies: glib, gtk3, webkitgtk3)
gio-0.13.3.1 (missing dependencies: glib, gtk2hs-buildtools)
glib-0.13.4.1 (missing dependencies: gtk2hs-buildtools)
gtk2hs-buildtools-0.13.2.2 (missing dependencies: happy)
gtk3-0.14.6 (missing dependencies: cairo, gio, glib, gtk2hs-buildtools, pango)
haskell-src-exts-1.17.1 (missing dependencies: happy)
haskell-src-meta-0.6.0.14 (missing dependencies: haskell-src-exts)
here-1.2.9 (missing dependencies: haskell-src-meta)
hs-di-0.4.0 (missing dependencies: haskell-src-meta, interpolate, interpolatedstring-perl6)
interpolate-0.1.0 (missing dependencies: haskell-src-meta)
interpolatedstring-perl6-1.0.0 (missing dependencies: haskell-src-meta)
pango-0.13.3.1 (missing dependencies: cairo, glib, gtk2hs-buildtools)
reflex-0.5.0 (missing dependencies: haskell-src-exts, haskell-src-meta)
reflex-dom-0.4 (missing dependencies: ghcjs-dom, glib, gtk3, reflex, webkitgtk3, webkitgtk3-javascriptcore)
threepenny-gui-0.7.1.0
uuid-1.3.13
webkitgtk3-0.14.2.1 (missing dependencies: cairo, glib, gtk2hs-buildtools, gtk3, pango)
webkitgtk3-javascriptcore-0.13.2.0 (missing dependencies: glib, gtk2hs-buildtools, gtk3, webkitgtk3)
websockets-0.9.8.2
websockets-snap-0.10.0.0
```

@user2407038, what kind of information might help to start diagnosing this? Is the above helpful to begin with? Under what circumstances can ever such an unregister-loop arise?

I have one more idea that I could try: this particular project depends on a few local packages, and afaik their `.stack-work` folder may play a role in this. So maybe I could (re)move those as well.

Any more ideas should the above one fail?

Comment: Unless this happens to be a known bug, there is not nearly enough information here to diagnose this. To downgrade, get the source [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/tree/v1.4.0) and build it (I can't find 1.4.1 but 1.4.0 is pretty close. Alternatively, browse the tree manually to find 1.4.1)

Comment: I just ran into this problem with `stack build --profile`, where it would unregister all packages every time. Doing `stack build -dry-run --profile` revealed that one package (parser-combinators) continuously failed to set the profile flag correctly. I was able to fix the problem by manually doing `stack install --profile parser-combinators; stack build --profile megaparsec; stack build --profile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short: changing `resolver: lts-7.19` to `resolver: lts-7.24` in `stack.yaml` seems to have fixed the error for me.

---

I have some guesses and hunches what may have gone wrong in the background, but I am not entirely sure.

I got a clue from the `--dry-run` flag that some of the missing packages it reports are build-time haskell package dependencies, like `alex`, `happy`, etc...

So maybe the older `lts` didn't install those correctly? If someone is more knowledgeable on the subject, I'd love to hear more.

And I'm also sad that this incident has destroyed some of my trust in stack's promise of reproducible builds, as a (AFAIK purported-to-be-safe) `stack upgrade` (and even with subsequent downgrade) suddenly left one of my projects un-buildable for days.

And at any rate, I'd love if

1. `stack` would warn and ask me before it makes destructive changes on my system, especially if it results in hours of recompilation. (Which actually meant days of head-scratching in my case since any idea I tried I had to wait quite a bit of time in-between.)
2. It could employ a similar build store as nix, whereas even if I change some configuration, I can switch back to the previous working configuration readily.

Answer (score 0):

As a partial solution, I found that I can

```
stack upgrade --binary-version 1.4.0
```

Which readily performs the downgrade:

```
Current Stack version: 1.5.1, available download version: 1.4.0
Forcing binary upgrade
Querying for archive location for platform: linux-x86_64-static
Downloading from: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/releases/download/v1.4.0/stack
-1.4.0-linux-x86_64-static.tar.gz
Download complete, testing executable
Version 1.4.0, Git revision e714f1dd3fade19496d91bd6a017e435a96a6bcd (4640 commits) x86_64 
hpack-0.17.0
New stack executable available at /home/user/.local/bin/stack
```

Answer (score 0):

It could have been the case the you were hitting this bug: [Better calculation of SourceMap](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3922), but again not enough information to tell for sure. Considering that this issue will get fixed soon, it shouldn't be a problem anymore, but if anyone is looking for a work around [custom snapshots](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/07/stacks-new-extensible-snapshots) seem to work pretty well.

The gist of custom snapshots is by moving all immutable packages from `extra-deps` into a custom snapshot will prevent stack from recalculating dependencies for these packages.